# C# UnitTest Method Result

Tags: c#, return-type, unit-testing

I would like to test this method using UnitTest, but I have no clue how to approach to this return type
even the method does not make sens or anything

```
public Result ChangeVoucherStatus(long[] voucherIDs, GenericStatus newStatus, Context context)
{
    ... 
    return new Result(true, resMsg);
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and NUnit test adapter 
Any suggestions?

I have tested the void methods but this scared me.

Comment: Its all the same thing. You just need to capture the return from your tested item (ie your `Result` object) and then make sure it looks right (eg that your boolean is correct given your inputs or that your mresMsg says the same thing). If the method doesn't make sense then you might need to sort that out before worrying about testing it...

Comment: What is of type Result - is that custom type ?

Comment: in Unit test i need to catch the `Object Result` and get out of that 2 things `boolean` and `message` is that correct?
*and method does not make sens here, here in this question

Comment: @user37202: broadly yes. The idea is that you can test internal behaviour the same as with a void method. In this case though you also need to check that your returned object is as expected. How you determine if it is as expected is for you to establish. You may be able to just compare it to a `Result` object that you've created manually or you may have to test key properties individually. Essentially it boils down to if you know the input you should know the output so you can test the output is what it should be.

Comment: it is just a return type in this case it is object
   took me a while to figure it out 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with xunit

You can do something like that

```
[Fact]
public void TestChangeVoucherStatus(){

   var vocherIDs = ...;
   var newStatus = ...;
   var context = ...;

   var result = ChangeVoucherStatus(voucherIDs, newStatus, context);

   Assert.Equal(result.resMsg, "")

}
```

with nunit

```
[TestFixture]
class Test {
    [Test]
    public void TestChangeVoucherStatus(){

       var vocherIDs = ...;
       var newStatus = ...;
       var context = ...;

       var result = ChangeVoucherStatus(voucherIDs, newStatus, context);

       Assert.Equal(result.resMsg, "")

    }
...
}
```

Comment: that is with XUnit but what about NUnit?